# Load testing of 100 user using jmeter on asp.net application giving error on jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing

I am doing load testing on my asp.net application using jmeter for only 100 user.

I am having jquery on page "Scripts/jquery.min.js" Jquery is present in folder. The error is as following on 20% of user.

`**sample result** :- Thread Name: Thread Group 1-25
Sample Start: 2014-07-31 11:45:43 IST
Load time: 189003
Latency: 0
Size in bytes: 2000
Headers size in bytes: 0
Body size in bytes: 2000
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Response code: Non HTTP response code: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException
Response message: Non HTTP response message: Remote host closed connection during handshake

Response headers:

HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: null`

**request - GET** https://www.mydomain.com/Scripts/jquery.min.js

[no cookies]

Request Headers:
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0(WindowsNT6.2;WOW64;rv:21.0)Gecko/20100101Firefox/21.0
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

**responcedata** - javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:436)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:643)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:481)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:298)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase$ASyncSample.call(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1826)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase$ASyncSample.call(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1794)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase$1$1.run(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1257)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    ... 21 more

Note : I have tried 100 user.  80 user haven't get this error rest 20 user get this error. Server is very much strong. it is on cloud server with high configuration. I am trying only 100 user and only 80% is success rate. 20% I am getting failure response.

Please share your idea.

Comment: check connection limit on the server, since the error clearly signifies "remote host closed connection during handshake."

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `https.use.cached.ssl.context=false` in *jmeter.properties* file. It can be also overriden in *user.properties* file or set for a single run via -J command line argument as

```
jmeter -Jhttps.use.cached.ssl.context=false -n -t /path/to/your/test/plan.jmx -l /path/to/results.jtl
```

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](http://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for properties configuration advanced information.

Comment: I have try this not working for me. thank you for your valuable reply.

Answer (score 1):

The SSL handshake failure in the stack trace can be due to either the client side and/or the server side.  To find which one is responsible, you could use wireshark (or other network packet sniffer) to capture all the packets and find a TCP session that has the failed SSL handshake.

Finding a TCP session among all the captured packet may take some work.  One trick is to export all the packet summary into a text file and write a script to search for the "bad" tcp session.  You may be happy that you come to know more about SSL than ever ;-)

Comment: I have try this not working for me. thank you for your valuable reply.